# How can i loop 2 different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

My program is basically playing Tic tac toe with 2 players which each one runs on a different thread. Now my problem is that i dont know how to keep running both threads one after another until one of the players win. This is my code:

```
            final HumanPlayer p1 = new HumanPlayer();
            final HumanPlayer p2 = new HumanPlayer();
            Thread tr1 = new Thread()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        
                            System.out.printf("Player %s's turn\n",p1Name);
                            System.out.printf("Insert row number:\n");
                            row = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                            System.out.printf("Insert column number:\n");
                            col = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                            p1.fillBoard(p1.index(row,col),board,1);
                            p1.printBoard(board);   
                            if(p1.checkWin(board, p1Name) != null)
                            {
                                System.out.printf("Player %s won.\n",p1Name);
                            }
                        
                    }
                };
            Thread tr2 = new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    
                        System.out.printf("Player %s's turn\n",p2Name);
                        System.out.printf("Insert row number:\n");
                        row = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                        System.out.printf("Insert column number:\n");
                        col = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                        p2.fillBoard(p2.index(row,col),board,2);
                        p2.printBoard(board);
                        if(p2.checkWin(board, p2Name) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.printf("Player %s won.\n",p2Name);
                        }
                    
                }
            };

                tr1.start();
                tr1.join();
                tr2.start();
                tr2.join();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your launch sequence:

```java
tr1.start();
tr2.start();
tr1.join();
tr2.join();
```

This will start both threads and then await until they're done doing work. You're still missing some essential pieces in your code like the while loop to keep solving until the game is done and synchronizing the turns between your threads which is off-scope of this current question.

Comment: I had a loop in every run() which stopped once the player reached the win. Problem was that it kept looping the same player and never reached the second player. I'll try what u suggested with that solution now.

Comment: it just starts both thread before i put my input and crashes after. The code i posted works fine but only runs once.

Comment: You need to synchronize both threads to perform such task which is kind of a big task. You were launching one and then the other one and that's why it worked. Your code waited for Thread1's execution to finish and then launch the second one. I have no way to tell what you're trying to achieve but you can wrap each Thread's code into a method and do: `while(game.notWon() { pl1.makeMove(); pl2.makeMove(); }` Without using any Threads what so ever. Multithreading and task synchronization is not a simple topic :)